# Visual Basic web: Strange Label styling

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I have this issue with the styling of a rather complicated label.

The style in the css code does not always get applied as it should. In fact I h ran this code on 2 different Machines and do get different style-results.

I find this code rather disgusting, in how long and un-organized it is.
But all I want is to apply the css styling without changeing the label *onclick*-functionality.

css-attributes that work: color, padding, float, background.

Rest of the css-attributes does not work. **Why?**

The code looks like this

**aspx:**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblResetOrder" CssClass="resetRequest" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

**css:**

```
.resetRequest {
color:#7baa0f;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 150%;
text-decoration: underline;
padding-left:8px;
float:right;
background:url(../Images/General/HyperLinkArrow.gif) left 4px no-repeat;
}
```

**code behind:**

```
For Each gvr As GridViewRow In gvRequests.Rows

CType(gvr.FindControl("lblResetOrder"), Label).Attributes.Add("onclick", "EnableCheckBoxes('" & CType(gvr.FindControl("chkbDeny"), CheckBox).ClientID & "', '" & CType(gvr.FindControl("chkbApprove"), CheckBox).ClientID & "', '" & CType(gvr.FindControl("lblResetOrder"), Label).ClientID & "')")
```

**result html:**

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvRequests_ctl02_lblResetOrder" class="resetRequest" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand';" onclick="EnableCheckBoxes('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvRequests_ctl02_chkbDeny', 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvRequests_ctl02_chkbApprove', 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvRequests_ctl02_lblResetOrder')">Nollställ</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styling has nothing to do with your server code. Just look at the generated html.

Start with the most basic tag:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .resetRequest {
  color:#7baa0f;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-left:8px;
  float:right;
  background:url(../Images/General/HyperLinkArrow.gif) left 4px no-repeat;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="resetRequest">Nollställ</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does that work for you? It looks fine for me.

If that looks fine, investigate other stuff on your page, add the JavaScript events back to the span. Do you have an document ready event or other styles that could affect your span?

Answer (score 0):

I have not attempted the suggested database way of generating this HTML.
I found out that the simple **CSS styling was not have any effect due to IIS needing to be updated**. Thanks for the answer, irregardless. Much appreciated.

During this time I did not have access to stadard debugging.